# Grails 2.3.8 oAuth2 - authorization error

Tags: grails, oauth, oauth-2.0, grails-plugin

after upgrade from grails 2.2.1 to grails 2.3.8 I have problem with authorization in oAuth.
I'm using grails 2.3.8 with :

```
compile (":spring-security-oauth2-provider:1.0.5.2")
```

I add to config.groovy following lines:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.providerNames = [
        'daoAuthenticationProvider',
        'anonymousAuthenticationProvider',
        'rememberMeAuthenticationProvider',
        'clientCredentialsAuthenticationProvider'
]
```

the rest is taken from my old config.
Now when I'm trying to authorize I'm geting error.
How can I do this:
My authorize path looks:

- login to grails app with spring security (send post user and pass to
  : j_spring_security_check)
- when I logged, I want to authorize with:

  http://test.domain.com:8080/app/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=clientId&redirect_uri=http://test.domain.com:8080/app/

But then I'm getting:

```
| Error 2014-04-27 23:09:25,623 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - InvalidRequestException occurred when processing request: [POST] /fis-bps/oauth/authorize - parameters:
user_oauth_approval: true
response_type: code
redirect_uri: http://test.domain.com:8080/tis-bpp
client_id: tis-bpp-and
Cannot approve uninitialized authorization request.. Stacktrace follows:
Message: Cannot approve uninitialized authorization request.
    Line | Method
->>   53 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|     49 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter
|     82 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
```

Anyone can help me ?